# Display PDF in Firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, pdf, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

How can I view PDF files in my Firemonkey application?

I tried to add Adobe reader ActiveX into my project, but I've got an error!!

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and the error you are getting. People can not help if you do not give details.

Comment: I do exactly what I done in VCL project to add Adobe reader ActiveX, but in Firemonkey the component does not appear in Tool Palette window!!!

Answer (score 3):

I current showing pdf in firemonkey with Adobe Pdf Reader Active X, here the code:

```
ACRO := TAcroPDF.Create( Self );
ACRO.Width := Width;
ACRO.Height := Height;
ACRO.ParentWindow := FmxHandleToHWND( Self.Handle );
ACRO.LoadFile( 'C:\ProgramData\teste.PDF' );
// if focus no set, user need click on activeX component
ACRO.SetFocus;
```

Note: you need add uses "FMX.PlatForm.Win" and import activeX to you project. Normally the file generate is "AcroPDFLib_TLB.pas" you need add this to uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can not host ActiveX controls in firemonkey.  There is no PDF display component that I know of for Firemonkey, but if there was, it would have to be implemented separately or with a lot of conditional defines under the hood so it could work on both Mac OS X and Windows.

I am aware of ways that you can put one Firemonkey form into a VCL application but not aware of any way you can do the reverse.  In short there is no easy way to do this, and the shortest path would be to write your own component, which would have to somehow host a PDF viewer either as an OLE Object or ActiveX control on Windows, and be implemented some other way on Mac OS X.

Comment: May you help me to write a custom component with VCL and use in Firemonkey?

Comment: I create my application with firemonkey just for better UI, but firemonkey limits me against most of VCL abilities...

Comment: I think you've got the picture very clearly, yes indeed you have lots of new features, and lots of new limitations. Welcome to the Cross Platform Framework world.

Comment: P, But I don't use firemonkey for Cross Platform, I use it just for better UI and animations.

Comment: Still Firemonkey is what it is, it was designed around cross platform goals, not just "better UI and animations", but when you don't mind staying with Windows, a way to go into a "Windows only form or feature" in Firemonkey would be a nice thing for them to add to the product. (Ability to insert a regular VCL form with an ActiveX container inside it, etc).

Answer (score 2):

3 solutions:

1. If you must embed: try an embedded browser.

   - [DelphiChromiumEmbedded](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) works under FireMonkey (see [Demo](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn/trunk/demos/firemonkey))
   - According to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29), Chromium comes with pdf support built in since version 6.0.
2. Otherwise, you could always launch an external viewer.
3. Worst case scenario: convert your pdf's to html

Comment: Number 1 and 3 are same, because for showing html in firemonkey we have to use DelphiChromiumEmbedded ;-)

Comment: I didn't know dcef ran in firemonkey